# Calculate Dot Product between two arrays with MongoDB Aggregate

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents with the following format:

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('5a7884437443cfd470893efc'),
  'source': [1,2,3,3]
  'sink': [5,6,7,8]
}
```

How can I calculate the dot product between the source and sink arrays (vectors) using the aggregation pipeline

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming both arrays have the same length you can use below aggregation:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            dotProduct: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$source" }] },
                    initialValue: 0,
                    in: { $add: [ "$$value", { $multiply: [ { $arrayElemAt: [ "$source", "$$this" ] }, { $arrayElemAt: [ "$sink", "$$this" ] } ] } ] }
                }
            }
        }
    }    
])
```

[$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/) is used to generate an array of 4 elements in this case `(0,1,2,3)` and those are used as indexes for [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) operator. [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) simply sums all products for particular indexes returning scalar value. There are two special variables used in `$reduce`: `$$value` represents sum while `$$this` represents index generated by `$range`

Comment: @HassanSaif you mean more than two arrays ?

Comment: An alternate could use [`$zip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/zip/) instead of `$range` and just get the `0` and `1` indexes from each "zipped" element. But the logic says much the same, and just a few chars less to type. Unfortunately `$multiply` does not yet accept an array reference. If it did, then the expression would be notably shorter.