# Mongodb empty find({}) query taking long time to return docs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have ~19,000 docs in an mlab sandbox, total size ~160mb. I will have queries that may want a heavily filtered subset of those docs, or completely unfiltered. In all cases, the information I need returned is a 100-length array that is an attribute of each document. So in the case of no filter, I expect to get back 19k arrays which I will then do further processing on. The query I'm doing to test this is `db.find({}, { vector: 1 });`.

Using `.explain()`, I can see that this query doesn't take long at all. However, it takes upwards of 50 seconds for my code to see the returned data. At first I thought it was simply downloading a bunch of data taking a long time, but the total vector data size is only around 20mb, which shouldn't take that long. (For context, my nodejs server is running locally on my pc while the db is hosted, so there will be some transfer).

What is taking this so long? An empty query shouldn't take any time to execute, and projecting the results into only vectors means I should only have to download ~20mb of data, which should be a matter of seconds.

Comment: There are far too many possible factors at play here. That being said, it doesn't sound like your `find()` is the issue, but rather the data transfer rate. Some considerations: 1. You're using the mLab sandbox which is a single, shared `mongod` instance in a VM, so resources just might not be available. Recommended might be to try e.g. DigitalOcean or AWS and see if performance improves. 2. MongoDB cursors retrieve subsets of the data in "batches", and each retrieval will incur network overhead. 3. Your `node.js` server might have too few resources available, particularly memory.

Comment: There are a number of other possibilities as well. My recommendation is to watch your network activity and see what the data transfer rate is when retrieving the data. If it's low, which I suspect, you'll want to check if it's the mLab instance or the `node.js` instance that's at fault. Those are probably your most likely bottleneck sources. My money is on this being a problem with the mLab sandbox simply not providing a high enough data transfer rate.

Comment: @B.Fleming I upgraded to the 1gb Shared Cluster level of mlab (as seen here: https://elements.heroku.com/addons/mongolab), but that didn't affect my results at all. When the query is ongoing, I do notice my local network's traffic is downloading at around ~300kb/s, which means around 80 seconds for 20mb of data, so maybe that's the issue...

Comment: Yes, that would absolutely be the issue. What does a speedtesting website report as your network download speed? If it's within a similar range, then the issue is your own network speed being the bottleneck.

Comment: @B.Fleming I get ~80Mb/s on a speedtesting website, so I think it's just the pipe from mlab to my pc probably. This isn't an ideal solution for my use case anyway (ideally mongo would have custom sort functions and then I wouldn't have this issue), so I'll have to look at other stuff. Thanks for the help!

Comment: For the record, MongoDB has custom sorting built in. You need to either perform the sorting via the appropriate `sort()` method or, if you need something more complicated via dynamically-computed values, you can perform the sorting through the use of [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/).

Comment: @B.Fleming I need to sort by cosine similarity (each doc I have has pre-calculated vectors), which as far as I've seen isn't directly supported in aggregation or sorting?

Comment: You can [calculate a dot product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394051/calculate-dot-product-between-two-arrays-with-mongodb-aggregate). If you modify that example to replace one of the arrays with your reference vector, it should work. Using another projection stage, you can also calculate the magnitude portion. With these two calculations in place, it should then be possible to perform one final projection dividing the two values to store the cosine similarity, and finally sort by this similarity value.

Comment: Granted, if there is another tool with out-of-the-box support for this kind of use case, it probably is much better to migrate your data over to that tool. If you want to continue making use of MongoDB if possible, however, then it should absolutely be possible :)

Comment: @B.Fleming That makes sense. However, the reference vector comes from one of my docs (i.e. a search term is given, it returns one doc, and that doc's vector is the reference one). Is it possible to set up an aggregation pipeline that 1) finds that ref vec, 2) calculates the dot product of every doc to that ref vec, and 3) calculates the magnitude and therefore the final similarity?

Comment: You're using a `node.js` server to make the connection, right? Retrieve the reference document and then stuff its data into the appropriate parts of the projection stages of the aggregation pipeline. You can use any mix of external values and values from documents in the pipeline. A two-part query shouldn't cause any problems :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195098/discussion-between-ironwaffleman-and-b-fleming).